Error in translating the Laplacian in polar coordinates
I am translating the Laplacian into polar coordinates and somewhere in this process something goes wrong. I wish someone of you might help.
Premise: some notation might not be the best, if this effectively cause the problem, please let me know.
Let the change of coordinates map be
\begin{align}
\eta: \mathbb R_{\geq}\times (-\pi, \pi]&\rightarrow \mathbb R^2\\ (r,\theta)&\mapsto (x,y):=(r \cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta))
\end{align}
and assume in a first moment that we use the standard basis for $\mathbb R^2$, hence $E_2 :=(e_1,e_2)$.
Given a regular point $(r,\theta)\in domain(\eta)$ and an arbitrary function $u\in C^2(\mathbb R^2,\mathbb R)$, the standard (hence referring to $E_2$) representation of the differential is the Jacobi matrix of the composition $u\circ\eta$ and is given by
$$D_{(r,\theta)}(u\circ\eta)  = D_{(x,y)}u \cdot D_{(r,\theta)}\eta$$ with $(x,y)=\eta(r,\theta)$. By transposing the equality one gets (with respect to the usual matrix multiplication)
$$\nabla (u\circ\eta) (r,\theta)= \nabla\eta (r,\theta)\cdot \nabla u(x,y)$$
I will now denote $\nabla(u\circ\eta)(r,\theta) := \nabla_{(r,\theta)}u = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:r}\\ \frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:\theta }\end{pmatrix}$, in hope that this won't turn out to be an unwise choice. So the RHS of the second equality happens to be
$$\nabla\eta (r,\theta)\cdot \nabla u(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix}\partial_r x & \partial_r y\\ \partial_\theta x& \partial_\theta y \end{pmatrix}\cdot \nabla u(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix}\cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta)\\ -r\sin(\theta) & r\cos(\theta) \end{pmatrix}\cdot \nabla u(x,y)$$
Now I will proceed by first of all obtaining the gradient operator in polar form, so
one has form above
\begin{align}
\nabla_{(r,\theta)}u &= \nabla\eta(r,\theta) \cdot \nabla u\\
\big(\nabla\eta(r,\theta)\big)^{-1} \cdot \nabla_{(r,\theta)}u &= \nabla u\\
\Longrightarrow \big(\nabla\eta(r,\theta)\big)^{-1} \cdot \nabla_{(r,\theta)} &= \nabla
\end{align}
where in the last row I omitted the arbitrary function $u$. Here, computing the matrix gives $$\big(\nabla\eta(r,\theta)\big)^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & -\frac{\sin(\theta)}{r} \\
\sin(\theta) & \frac{\cos(\theta)}{r}
\end{pmatrix}$$
and consequently by calculating $$\nabla  = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos \left(θ\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial r} - \frac{\sin \left(θ\right)}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial θ} \\
\sin \left(θ\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial r} + \frac{\cos \left(θ\right)}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial θ}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
To conclude the process to obtain the gradient now it's only needed to change the basis of the vector space to express the gradient in the parametric "polar" basis $S_2:=(s_1,s_2)$, recalling that until now the gradient was expressed in the same standard coordinates as above. This is done using the change of basis matrix
$$\,_{E_2}[id]_{S_2} = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)
\end{pmatrix}$$ and its inverse.
So now finally one can compute the gradient in its polar basis:
$$\nabla= \,_{S_2}[id]_{E_2}\cdot \big(\nabla\eta(r,\theta)\big)^{-1}\cdot \nabla_{(r,\theta)} = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial }{\partial r} \\ \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\end{pmatrix}_{S_2}$$
Now it comes the problem, or at last I think, as I have to compute the Laplacian in polar form. $\nabla\cdot\nabla u = 
\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}= \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} + \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \theta^2}$ should be the correct result, but unfortunately this is different from $\frac{\partial^2 u }{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \theta^2}$, which is the computation that I get, expressed with the result in the last row here above. Technically I shouldn't have even changed the object $\nabla$, only having expressed it differently. So... why does this happen? What didn't go the way it should have?
Another thing that one can do is to even suppose that the Laplacian is given as inner product: if we consider another change of basis to go back from $S_2$ to $E_2$, since for any $\theta \in (-\pi,\pi]$ the change of basis matrix is equal to the rotation matrix $Rot(\theta)$ for which $Rot(\theta)^{-1}= Rot(\theta)^T$. Even if we change the basis of the inner product, these matrices cancle out together as in between the standard scalar product is given by the identity matrix. So not even this should explain the wrong result that I obtained.
Thank you in advance for you attention and time.

The correct expression is the one you have: $$\Delta f=\frac1r\partial_r\Big(r,\partial_rf\Big)+\frac1{r^2}\partial_\theta^2f=
\partial_r^2f+\frac1r\partial_rf+\frac1{r^2}\partial_\theta^2f,.$$ See WP. It is quite unclear why you think that this is unfortunate. To clarify your post you may want to number the equations.

@KurtG. I will edit the post, but what I mean is that the equation that you also reported is the correct one, but with the approach I used, I get the answer reported just aside and without the central term.

Ma cosa hai fumato? Cambia pusher
